# Weird question about probability density function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

[image]

I'm assuming "actual" means the total probability of the PDF (the integral from $-\infty to \infty$) must be 1, so

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} ke^{-0.1t}dt = 1$$

Wolfram Alpha seems to be ambiguous regarding the antiderivative of this function, so can somene write it down for me? I'm sure I can complete this as soon as I have that.

Comment: You have the wrong density function, it is $0$ for $t\lt 0$. An antiderivative is $-\frac{k}{0.1}e^{-0.1t}$.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_T(t)\,dt=1.$$
Note that in the material you quoted, it says that the density function is $0$ for $t\lt 0$. Thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_T(t)\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^0 0\,dt+\int_{0}^\infty ke^{-0.1t}\,dt.$$
So we want to choose $k$ such that 
$$\int_{0}^\infty ke^{-0.1t}\,dt=1.$$

An antiderivative of $ke^{-0.1 t}$ is $-\frac{k}{0.1}e^{-0.1t}$.